# Function that returns a query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is the function :

```
create or replace function searchbyid (depto in departments.department_id%type) 

return sys_refcursor 

is result_s sys_refcursor; 

begin 

open result_s for 

SELECT 

a.employee_id, 

a.first_name, 

a.last_name, 

a.phone_number, 

a.salary, 

b.department_id, 

b.end_date 

FROM 
employees a
 
FULL JOIN job_history b ON a.department_id = b.department_id 

WHERE b.department_id = depto; 

return result_s; 

end;
```

I'm getting the output in a single line, is it possible to get as a table?
FUNCTION OUTPUT :

[image]

Yes, I use SQL Developer

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a [ref cursor](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use ref cursor (as Abra commented). I don't have your tables so I used Scott's.

```
SQL> create or replace function searchbyid (par_deptno in dept.deptno%type)
  2  return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for
  7      select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename, e.job, e.sal
  8      from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  9      where d.deptno = par_deptno;
 10
 11    return rc;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> select searchbyid(10) result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- -------------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK      MANAGER         2450
        10 ACCOUNTING     KING       PRESIDENT       5000
        10 ACCOUNTING     MILLER     CLERK           1300


SQL>
```

---

Another option is a pipelined function:

Types first:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_row as object
  2    (deptno    number,
  3     dname     varchar2(10),
  4     ename     varchar2(10),
  5     job       varchar2(10),
  6     sal       number
  7    );
  8  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_tab is table of t_row;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function searchbyid (par_deptno in dept.deptno%type)
  2    return t_tab pipelined
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename, e.job, e.sal
  6                  from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  7                  where d.deptno = par_deptno
  8                 )
  9    loop
 10      pipe row (t_row(cur_r.deptno, cur_r.dname, cur_r.ename, cur_r.job, cur_r.sal));
 11    end loop;
 12    return;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.

SQL> select * from table(searchbyid(10));

    DEPTNO DNAME      ENAME      JOB               SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING CLARK      MANAGER          2450
        10 ACCOUNTING KING       PRESIDENT        5000
        10 ACCOUNTING MILLER     CLERK            1300

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT, after you edited the question]**

Screenshot shows how data look like when function returns ref cursor in SQL Developer. If you want to see it *nicely*, scroll far right and click the pencil icon; something like this:

(click on (1) to get result as (2))

[image]

Comment: It works but it shows everything in a single line, is it possible to show as a table?

Comment: Excuse me? What is in a single line? In my example, there are 3 lines.

Comment: This is the output that i get : {<EMPLOYEE_ID=201,FIRST_NAME=Michael,LAST_NAME=Hartstein,PHONE_NUMBER=515.123.5555,SALARY=13000,DEPARTMENT_ID=20,END_DATE=19-DEC-07>,<EMPLOYEE_ID=202,FIRST_NAME=Pat,LAST_NAME=Fay,PHONE_NUMBER=603.123.6666,SALARY=6000,DEPARTMENT_ID=20,END_DATE=19-DEC-07>,} Mine is show like this. Everything in a single line.

Comment: This is my code :                                                              
 create or replace function searchbyid (depto in departments.department_id%type)

return sys_refcursor
is 
result_s sys_refcursor;
begin 
open result_s for
SELECT
    
    a.employee_id,
    a.first_name,
    a.last_name,
    a.phone_number,
    a.salary,
    b.department_id,
    b.end_date
   
FROM
    employees   a
    FULL JOIN job_history b ON a.department_id = b.department_id
    WHERE b.department_id = depto;
    return result_s;
    end;

Comment: As you probably see, that's unreadable. Please, post that information (properly formatted) by editing the original message you posted (the question itself). If you think that screenshot illustrates it better, attach it as well. By the way, which tool do you use? Is it SQL Developer (as you used that tag)?

Comment: I edited the post as you requested. Thank you for the tips. Yes, I use SQL Developer.

Comment: Thanks; I edited the answer as well. Have a look, please.